# Calling method from another view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

i am passing a value ViewControllerA  through  segue to ViewControllerB. in ViewControllerB i write a function in which i am returning the value which i got from A to whoever call this function

ViewControllerB

```
-(int)ButtonTagValue
{
NSlog("selected Button Value is %i ", selectedButtonValue)    
return selectedButtonValue;

}
```

in `ViewControllerC`  i am trying to access this function like this

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
  viewControllerB.ButtonTagValue
```

but this function is not coming into the selection after `.` operator. how can i access ButtonTagValue function in ViewControllerC because i need `buttonselectedValue.` or i am doing something wrong here. please let me know. my oop concepts are not good much

Comment: Why to you call a method with a dot? You should name your methods/var beginning with a lowercase. You created a new ViewControllerB, whereas I think you wanted to access one already existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `-(int)ButtonTagValue` function in **ViewControllerB.h**

and call it like this: `int retValue = [ViewControllerB ButtonTagValue];`

Comment: What makes this answer better then the answer that as already been given. It seems like the same answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should not allocate a viewcontroller when you navigate through segue.

2) If you have not declared your property you cannot access your getter method via `.` operator.

```
 int i = [viewControllerB ButtonTagValue];
```

call the method like this.